# Monitoring without keystroke logging

Tags: windows, windows-7

I'm looking for software to monitor PC usage. This software will be used in an academic environment, so we would like to avoid any kind of identifying data: keystroke logging, site visits, etc. I just want to install something on a given set of computers, and the software will tell me how many hours per day the PCs are used.

These are kiosk machines that are booted up and logged in early in the morning, and they stay on all day under the same user ID, so I can't simply go by login hours per day.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: This might get you in the right direction:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-do-i-view-login-history-for-my-pc-using/a0172887-1071-47fb-b0a3-6ca9360efdbf

Comment: (For Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/q/41262/44876)

Comment: So you want to monitor amount of time the mouse or keyboard is in use? And without logging keystrokes or sites...?

Comment: @shub Yes, I'm only interested *that* the keyboard and mouse are in use, not in recording exactly what the user was doing. Given that these are kiosks, I'll assume they are in use if there is keyboard/mouse activity.